# Ввод массива символов в си

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    char c;
    int len=0, k=0;
    printf ("Input the length of the array:\n");

    scanf("%d", &len);
    char str[len];
    
    for(int i = 0; i<len; i++){
        printf("a[%d] = ", i);
        scanf("%c", &str[i]);
    }
    printf("Result: \n");

    while(str[k] != '\0'){
        printf("%c", str[k]);
        k++;
    }

    

    getchar();
    getchar(); 
}
```

После того как запускаю программу, получаю a[0] = a[1] = , т.е. почему то пропускается 1 ввод. Что подскажете с этим можно сделать ?

Comment: [scanf(" %c", ...)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fscanf.3p.html) (т.е. добавьте пробел перед `%с` в формате. Пробельные символы, в т.ч. `\n` будут пропущены)

Comment: @Harry, imho  вы предложили ответ не на этот вопрос. Тут же дело не только в оставленном в потоке `\n`, но и в существенной разнице поведения  **`"%c"`** и ***`" %c"`*** (всего один пробел, а ведет себя совсем не так...)

Comment: @avp Проблема же именно в том, что конец строки в буфере остался и потом читается, нет? Нет, если вы настаиваете, я проголосую за переоткрытие, но, по-моему, это как раз та же проблема. Кстати, вы не хотите этот момент про `%c` дописать в качестве ответа в тот вопрос, на который ссылка?

Comment: @Harry, уже в первом комментарии я написал про пробел и scanf, надеюсь ТС-у (после прочтения вашего ответа по отсылке) уже все будет понятно. Так не будем разводить лишнюю тягомотину

Comment: @avp И все же мне кажется полезным ответ по ссылке о пробеле. Просто личная просьба... :)

Comment: @Harry, конечно (лишних знаний не бывает)